# how to embed css in sass, or use + selector in sass?

Tags: css, sass

I need create a css like this:

```
  .word-remain+textarea{clear: before}
```

but I cannot write this in sass:

```
  .word-remain+textarea
    clear: before
```

How can I do it?

Comment: theres nothing wrong, it compiles correctly into .word-remain + textarea { clear: before; }, check your text-indents and error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two levels of indentation.  This is probably why it does not work.

```
.word-remain+textarea
  clear: before
```

compiles as expected